# Latency issue in processing user requests in between the file upload processing

Tags: azure, redis, architecture, priority-queue, azure-eventhub

Below architecture using Standard tier Azure event hub with 32 partitions has to serve the user requests as well as file uploads, if the file uploads of big size happens & then user request happening at the same time gets landed at the back of the Azure event hub partition, this situation results in delay processing the user request till file upload processing gets completed.

How to address the latency issue in processing the user requests while receiving the large file upload as well? I mean the user request processing speed should not get affected by the volume of file upload happening at any given point in time.

[image]

Comment: Why file uploads are going to Azure Event Hub?

Comment: there is a processor sits in-between the Event hub and Fileupload, which parse each line in the file, converts it to message & post it to eventhub. If file has 1 million lines you can expect 1 millon message in eventhub with in few milliseconds, by that time if user makes request it will be queued up after the message came via file upload & results in delay processing user request, how we avoid delay in processing user request on any given circumstances? will redis queue supports any feature to handle user requests differently.

Comment: What does "processing use request" mean in this context?  Is an event being published or read?

Comment: event being read & taking further actions like calling api then updating respective DB objects etc

Comment: If user-initiated requests should have a higher priority than automated-by-file, have you considered separating them into different partitions?   For example, assuming an arbitrary 6 partitions, send the file-driven events to partitions 0, 1, 2, 3 and send user-driven events to partitions 4 and 5?

Comment: we are using standard tier Azure eventhub with 32 partitions, even with 32 partition dedicated for processing file driven events creates backlog most of the time, so providing subset of partitions for user driven events from total 32 partitions doesnt suits our requirement. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: If you can't segment by partition, then I'd suggest using another Event Hub.   As a stream, you can only read events contiguously in a forward-only manner.  There's no querying, filtering, or prioritization.   If you need to treat different sources differently, then you'll need to either split the traffic so that you can prioritize or consider something other than Event Hubs.   Perhaps, a Service Bus topic with different filtered subscriptions?